# How do I calculate the duration of alexa saying something?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

is there a way to calculate how long it will take Alexa to say a certain  phrase?

I would like to make Alexa read out a list of articles and be interrupted by the user, if they want to know more about the article Alexa last mentioned. Therefore I need to know the time it takes for Alexa to read out the article titles (in order to know where in list she has been when being interrupted).

Does somebody know a way to do that? Because the article titles are different everytime, manually measuring the time isn't possible.

Thanks in advance for any ideas & cheers from Hamburg
Timo

Comment: why not find out programmatically w/ AVS what was last said?

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this one of two ways.

1. Place in words of varying length, and time them. Then make inferences based on 100% speech speed.
2. Set a timer across some of your larger, and smaller, article names and get a result set of that, to average it out.